# Rails 5 disable access to internet explorer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to know if this is possible. If so, how?

I would like to block users of different browsers, such as IE or Vivaldi. How would this be done? Through Javascript? If so, can it be spoofed? Or can server side config block access as well?

Comment: You can check the user agent in your controller and give a differential response based on that. (Here's one Gem for parsing UAs: https://github.com/gshutler/useragent). Browsers can alter their user agents (e.g. look in Chrome Developer tools), so this can be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block incoming requests it's better to do it at rack level instead in controllers.

You have to write your own middleware like this (not tested)

```
module Rack
  class BrowserBlocker
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      useragent = UserAgent.new(env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].to_s)
      if (useragent.name == :ie)
        #block action here
        #redirect or show a page
      else
        #pass action here, usually @app.call(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you want advanced features, use some middleware like [Rack::Attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack), take a look at [blocklists](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#blocklists)